# Slidetoggle()-issue on toggle up and down

Tags: jquery

I have an issue with `slidetoggle()`.

Let's say I have a div with some font awesome icons. When I click them, text slides up/down in this div, but that's not a problem.

```
<div id="textbox">
<li class="something"><i class="fa fa-something"></i></li> | 
<li class="somethingelse" <i class="fa fa-somethingelse"></i></li>
</div>
```

When icon 1 or 2 are clicked, it toggles some text:

```
<p id"text1">text1</p> or <p id="text2">text2</p>
```

and the jQuery I use to toggle different content when clicked is

```
$(function() {
$('.something').click(function(e) {
   $('#text1').slideToggle(1800);
 });
});


 $(function() {
 $('.somethingelse').click(function(e) {
 $('#text2').slideToggle(1800);
 });
});
```

And it works like a charm, toggling when an icon is clicked.

But if I don't "close" the toggle by clicking on the icon (I clicked to "display" the p) but click the other icon, it toggles on top of the one that is already showing.

Is it possible to toggle-close the text that is already showing automatically when the other icon is clicked, *before* the content of the second one is toggled? If so, how?

Comment: you could use a jQueryUI accordion

Answer (score 0):

change id $('#text1') with $('#text2');

$(function() {

$('.somethingelse').click(function(e) {
 $('#text2').slideToggle(1800);

});

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding "slideUp()" when one is clicked:

```
$(function() {
$('.something').click(function(e) {
$('#text1').slideToggle(1800);
$('#text2').slideUp(1800);
});
});
```

and viceverca

```
$(function() {
$('.something').click(function(e) {
$('#text2').slideToggle(1800);
$('#text1').slideUp(1800);
});
});
```

I can't stop hitting myselfe in the head right now, for not thinking about this right away..

*need more coffee.. must.have.more.coffee...*

Sorry guy's ;)